# How can I declare and initialize a package variable by SELECT

Tags: sql, oracle, variables, plsql, oracle11g

Can someone help me understand why I can declare a hardcoded date value in a package but not assign the value from a query? I've seen a number of examples (including the reference book) that show declarations of hardcoded values but I'm unable to locate examples of assigning values to variable through queries.

This is allowed:

```
create or replace package body PACKAGE_NAME AS
    tDate DATE := '2012-05-30';
    -- ...procedures follow
```

This is allowed:

```
create or replace package body PACKAGE_NAME AS
    tDate DATE := sysdate;
```

This is not allowed:

```
create or replace package body PACKAGE_NAME AS
    tDate DATE := select MAX(date_) from Table_Name;
```

I've tried a number of ways and I'm ok with it not working - I can use it as needed in the procedures themselves. But I'd like to know why I can't assign a value to `tDate` this way? The specific error is:

> Encountered the symbol 'SELECT' when expecting ....

Adding that I can get variable values assigned through queries in a stored procedure but the same process does not seem to work for package body.

```
PROCEDURE Proc_Name IS
tDate Date;
BEGIN
SELECT MAX(date_) into tDate from Table_Name;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to create a package initialization block in your package body.  This is a relatively arcane bit of PL/SQL package lore, but it's there and can be used.  Here's an example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE TEST_PKG IS
  tDate  DATE;
END TEST_PKG;
```

Here we've created a package spec which contains only a single DATE variable.  Now we'll create a simple body which initializes that variable using a SELECT statement:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY TEST_PKG IS
  -- package-private variables go first (if any)
(...) 
  -- then the public functions/procedures
(...)
  -- then a final BEGIN-END block which is the package initialization block
BEGIN
  SELECT SYSDATE
    INTO tDATE
    FROM DUAL;
EXCEPTION  -- you can have exception handlers in your initialization block
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    NULL;  -- pointless here, but this is just an example
    RAISE;
END TEST_PKG;
```

Now if you execute the following:

```
begin
  -- Test statements here
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('TEST_PKG.tDate = ' || TEST_PKG.tDate);
end;
```

it should print the current date.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: Thanks for responding to my question. This definitely seems like it should work although I haven't been able to fit it into my package. I get an "encountered symbol 'CREATE'" error. when I try to include the package body. This might just be a problem with my environment. I still don't see why they made it so that I can assign a hardocoded value but not a valid value through a query. Why must I implement this "arcane" method to set a variable value? Thanks again.

Comment: The package spec and body need to be created separately.  So you should have `CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE MY_PACKAGE...END MY_PACKAGE;` followed by `CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY MY_PACKAGE...END MY_PACKAGE;`.  As to "why must I..." - the long answer is that you can't use an executable statement, such as a SELECT, in a variable initialization, and this is precisely why the package initializer block exists - so that you can execute code at the time your session accesses a package that initializes package variables for your session.  The short answer is "because ya gotta".  :-)  Share and enjoy.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the why even though it seems like both the long and short answers are: "Why? Because it's science, that's why!" Dr.F. I still get a problem with it but I'll ask around and re-read the specs on oracle package construction and I'll probably figure it out over the weekend.

Comment: I don't see why you moved the variable declaration from the package body to the specification. It can be either place depending on whether you want it visible to the outside world.initialization.

Comment: @ShannonSeverance - really just for example purposes - I wanted to show an example of creating both the spec and the body, and so created the variable in the spec.  You're correct, of course, that the initialization block can deal with variables declared either place.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `INTO` when selecting directly into a variable.

```
select MAX(date_) 
INTO tDate
from Table_Name;
```

Comment: thanks for your fast response. I can get this to work for a stored procedure but not for a package. PROCEDURE Name_ is tDate DATE; BEGIN SELECT INTO tDate etc... but not for PACKAGE BODY Package_Name tDate DATE; SELECT MAX(date_) INTO etc....

Comment: A package body should contain procedure and function definitions, it is not itself a PL/SQL block. The tDate declaration is valid as a global for the package but the SELECT should appear inside a Procedure or Function.