# Unable to create a global variable in package

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I try to do the following :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE my_package AS
  -- Declare the global variable
  my_variable VARCHAR(255);
END my_package;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY my_package AS
  -- Assign a value to the global variable
  my_variable := 'test';
END my_package;
/
```

But this does highlight `:=` and throw the following error :

```
LINE/COL  ERROR
--------- -------------------------------------------------------------
3/15      PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "=" when expecting one of the following:     constant exception <an identifier>    <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> table columns long    double ref char time timestamp interval date binary national    character nchar The symbol "<an identifier>" was substituted for "=" to continue. 
Errors: check compiler log
```

How can I create a package with in it a global variable so I can use it as follow :

```
my_package.my_variable
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I declare and initialize a package variable by SELECT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851769/how-can-i-declare-and-initialize-a-package-variable-by-select)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use it in SQL then create a function to wrap the variable:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE my_package AS
  FUNCTION get_my_variable
  RETURN VARCHAR2;
END my_package;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY my_package AS
  -- Declare the package variable
  -- It can be public, if declared in the package specification
  -- Or private, if declared in the package body
  my_variable VARCHAR(255);

  FUNCTION get_my_variable
  RETURN VARCHAR2
  IS
  BEGIN
    RETURN my_variable;
  END;
BEGIN
  -- Assign a value to the global variable
  my_variable := 'test';
END my_package;
/
```

Then you can use it in SQL:

```sql
SELECT my_package.get_my_variable() FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| MY_PACKAGE.GET_MY_VARIABLE() |
| --- |
| test |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/DWK7ZaTD)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a BEGIN block:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY my_package AS
BEGIN
  -- Assign a value to the global variable
  my_variable := 10;
END my_package;
/
```

Comment: Thank you now code compile, now I wonder why when I do `my_package.my_variable ` it returns : 
ORA-06553: PLS-221: 'my_variable ' is not a procedure or is undefined
06553. 00000 -  "PLS-%s: %s"
*Cause:    SQL compilation failed because of an illegal reference to a
           PL/SQL unit.
*Action:   If the PL/SQL error message does not provide a workaround, then
           try the SQL statement as a top-level call as the appropriate user
           with the appropriate privileges.
Error at Line: 146 Column: 210

How can I Use My_Variable IN my a SQL Request ?